# error while generating script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created my database in sqlserver2008 r2,I want to degrade it to sqlserver2005.
I set the "SCRIPT For Server Version" option to 2005 while generating script,but I'm getting error with a table which has column with date data type.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the script manually from `date` to `datetime` or `smalldatetime`. SQL Server isn't going to do that automatically for data types, unfortunately.